# joomla 2.5 + vm2 пропали цены

Tags: joomla, virtuemart

на странице категорий, не показывает цены если нет скидки
Вот если в админке ovveride 0р и disabled то вообще никакие цены не показывает
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

код страницы категорий

```
            <?php                       
                if ($this->show_prices == '1') {
                    if( $product->product_unit && VmConfig::get('vm_price_show_packaging_pricelabel')) {
                               echo $this->currency->createPriceDiv ('priceWithoutTax', 'COM_VIRTUEMART_PRODUCT_SALESPRICE_WITHOUT_TAX', $product->prices);
                        echo "<strong>". JText::_('COM_VIRTUEMART_CART_PRICE_PER_UNIT').' ('.$product->product_unit."):</strong>";

                    }

                    //todo add config settings
                    if( $this->showBasePrice ){

                        echo $this->currency->createPriceDiv('basePrice','COM_VIRTUEMART_PRODUCT_BASEPRICE',$product->prices);
                        echo $this->currency->createPriceDiv('basePriceVariant','COM_VIRTUEMART_PRODUCT_BASEPRICE_VARIANT',$product->prices);
                    }



                    if ($product->prices['basePrice'] != $product->prices['salesPrice']) {
                      echo $this->currency->createPriceDiv ('priceWithoutTax', 'COM_VIRTUEMART_PRODUCT_SALESPRICE_WITHOUT_TAX', $product->prices);
                    echo $this->currency->createPriceDiv('variantModification','COM_VIRTUEMART_PRODUCT_VARIANT_MOD',$product->prices);
                    echo $this->currency->createPriceDiv('basePriceWithTax','COM_VIRTUEMART_PRODUCT_BASEPRICE_WITHTAX',$product->prices);
                    echo $this->currency->createPriceDiv('discountedPriceWithoutTax','COM_VIRTUEMART_PRODUCT_DISCOUNTED_PRICE',$product->prices);
                    echo $this->currency->createPriceDiv('salesPriceWithDiscount','COM_VIRTUEMART_PRODUCT_SALESPRICE_WITH_DISCOUNT',$product->prices);
                    echo $this->currency->createPriceDiv('salesPrice','COM_VIRTUEMART_PRODUCT_SALESPRICE'.(($product->prices['basePrice'] != $product->prices['salesPrice']) ? '_NEW' : ''),$product->prices);
                //  echo $this->currency->createPriceDiv('priceWithoutTax','COM_VIRTUEMART_PRODUCT_SALESPRICE_WITHOUT_TAX',$product->prices);
                    echo $this->currency->createPriceDiv('discountAmount','COM_VIRTUEMART_PRODUCT_DISCOUNT_AMOUNT',$product->prices);
                    echo $this->currency->createPriceDiv('taxAmount','COM_VIRTUEMART_PRODUCT_TAX_AMOUNT',$product->prices);
                    }
                } ?>
```

и вот как выглядит страница категорий
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2):

не оно (найдено прямо по вашему запросу где обычно, там еще много)? - 
http://joomfans.com/forum/joomla/rasshireniya-joomla/virtuemart-2-otobrazhenie-tsen-kak-sdelat/stranitsa-2.html

+ не забывайте, что компонент и модули могут быть переопределены в вашем шаблоне сайта